# Get JavaScript async/await result in Swift

Tags: swift, javascriptcore

I want to include external JavaScript file with async/await in my swift project.

So is there any way to run JS code like this in swift?

I was trying to use JavaScriptCore with jsContext.evaluateScript(“JS Code goes here”) but it doesn’t works as it should.

Here is an example of a JS function that I’m trying to run in swift:

```
async function asyncFunction() {

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("i am resolved!"), 1000)
  });

  const result = await promise; 
  // wait till the promise resolves (*)

  console.log(result); // "i am resolved!"
}

asyncFunction();
```

I expected to get the result after timeout, but I can’t get the desired values and results after some JS timeout in swift.

Comment: But Swift already has support for promises: Combine, PromiseKit, RxSwift, etc. Why would you want to use the JS one?

Comment: Actually it’s a requirement. So we want to send JS code to swift app(also android and web) and expect it to behave in one manner.

Comment: Well... any Promise implementation that follows the Promises/A+ specifications should behave the same regardless the programming language is developed into.

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to use that JS without any changes. I want to pass JS async/await code and catch the delayed result. Right now it executes immediately without waiting for the delayed result.

Comment: @fundamental3 Did you find a solution?
I have the same problem I need to run js async/await functions.

Comment: @ByurhanBeyzat I ended up implementing support for Promise in Swift. I also transpile the JS code to an older version which ends up removing async/await signatures.